# Visual Studio/Visual Basic Textbox receives only formatted date

Tags: vb.net, date, visual-studio-2012, format

i need to create some code, that will do the following. The user inputs only numbers, which i have coded with the key press event. Next is the length of the date can only be 8 characters long. mm/dd/yy Also inside this condition i need to have the month, day and year be stored in different variables so that i can validate individually if the correct date for each month, day, and year are correct. for instance we don't have more than 12 months in a year. So i was thinking about using substring to pull apart the one variable that holds the input of the textbox then validate individually.

I do realize that there is built-in functions but in this case i am not allowed to use them.

```
Private Sub btnCheckDate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheckDate.Click

Dim strDate As String
Dim badDate As Boolean = False

    strDate = txtInput.TabIndex
    If strDate.Length <> 8 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Bad date")
        txtInput.Text = String.Empty
        txtInput.Focus()
    End If

    Dim intMonth As Integer
    Dim intDay As Integer
    Dim intYear As Integer

    intMonth = CInt(strDate.Substring(0, 2))
```

Comment: Use `Date.ParseExact(strDate,"MM/dd/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` instead. You can use `Date.TryParseExact` with the same format to validate the input.

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not allowed to use built-in functions"? `Substring` is a "built-in function" (as is `Date.Parse` or any other method you might want to call).

Comment: I presume that means date validation functions.  Use substring to chop it up, convert to int, then validate each value.  I'd go for extra credit and allow 8 or 10 chars (MM/DD/YYYY) as it will only change how you collect the value for the year.  The go for Extra Extra credit to make each validation a called function returning T/F.  Hint: do month first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume when you say you can't use built in functions, you mean date/time functions. Here's one simple way of validating the text and putting each part into a variable:

```
Dim strDate As String = txtInput.Text
Dim intMonth As Integer
Dim intDay As Integer
Dim intYear As Integer
Dim badDate As Boolean = True
If strDate.Length = 8 Then
    Dim DateParts As List(Of String) = txtInput.Text.Split("/"c).ToList
    If DateParts.Count = 3 Then
        If Integer.TryParse(DateParts(0), intMonth) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(DateParts(1), intDay) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(DateParts(2), intYear) Then
            If intMonth <= 12 AndAlso intDay <= 31 AndAlso intYear <= 20 Then
                badDate = False
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
If badDate = True Then
    MessageBox.Show("Bad date")
    txtInput.Text = String.Empty
    txtInput.Focus()
End If
```

There's other validating that can be done months of different lengths and leap year. Just add more conditional statements.

I changed badDate to default to True it seems to make more sense when you read it.